# Shaky wireless with Asus PCI-N10

Tags: wireless, asus

It worked out of the box in my other PC and it did work during install but right now, sometimes it works fine and sometimes the connection is awefully slow even though reception is really good  and I can't do anything that requires an internet connection. No additional driver suggested. Is there any tests I can run?

Comment: Are You using a Wireless N Access Point?

Comment: Yes, it's a D-LINK DIR-615.

Answer (score 0):

Try Issuing the Following Commands in a Terminal:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
```

and

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

The First Command Will Turn Off the Wireless Service.
Thee Second will Restart it with the N Wireless Disabled

This is because there is a bug in Intel Wireless Cards that Makes it preform very slow when connected to wireless N Networks

Comment: There's no change.

Comment: It's got to be something else. Like I said it worked out of the box in my other PC. Really need help with this. Maybe the card is defect?